# Get the key value if the list element in two dicts shares any tuple

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, intersection

I have two dictionaries (`a`, `b`).

Each has many keys with different lengths of list. Each list has multiple tuples.

Is there any fast way to get the key of `a` if the cooresponding list has any shared tuple with `b` regardless of the key value of `b`?

Here's the example:

```
b = {41: [(37, 15), (36, 17), (36, 16), (35, 16), (36, 15)],
     42: [(40, 15), (44, 15), (40, 18), (44, 16)]}
a = {38: [(36, 18), (37, 15), (35, 16)],
     39: [(57, 0), (54, 0), (55, 0), (56, 0)]}

def test_overlap(a, b):
    overlap = frozenset(b).isdisjoint(a)
    return not overlap

list_remove = []
for id_b, b_i in b.items():
    for id_a, a_i in a.items():
        if test_overlap(a[id_a], b[id_b]):
            list_remove.append(id_a)

list_remove=list(set(list_remove))
print(list_remove)

# Output: [38]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a set out of all the tuples in `b` and use it to filter the items of `a`:

```
b = {41: [(37, 15), (36, 17), (36, 16), (35, 16), (36, 15)],
     42: [(40, 15), (44, 15), (40, 18), (44, 16)]}
a = {38: [(36, 18), (37, 15), (35, 16)],
     39: [(57, 0), (54, 0), (55, 0), (56, 0)]}

tb = set().union(*b.values())
r  = [ka for ka,ta in a.items() if not tb.isdisjoint(ta)]

print(r) # [38]
```

Comment: That's much faster than my suggestions, and the OP's.

Comment: Thanks! It improves a lot for my large datasets ;)